# Google Geocode V2 vs V3 with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, geocoding

I am having trouble with a PHP page and Google's Geocode service. I'm new at this, and may be overlooking something simple. I started with PHP code from Google's Geo Team written in 2007 and I believe my problem relates to adapting this Geocode V2 code the the current V3. Here are the three adaptations:

```
// Change the maps host, and keys are no longer used:
//define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com"); V2 Geocode
//define("KEY", "abcdefg"); V2 Geocode
define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.googleapis.com"); // V3 Geocode

// Change the base URL:
//$base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?output=xml" . "&key=" .  KEY V2 Geocode
$base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/api/geocode/xml?"; //V3 Geocode

// Change the request URL:
//  $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($address); V2 Geocode
$request_url = $base_url . "address=" . urlencode($address) . "&sensor=false";  V3 Geocode
```

I testing with four actual addresses in a MySQL database; these addresses come up normally in maps.google.com. Using the PHP below, all four addresses throw this error: 'This Address 1744 Crescent Ave, Idaho Falls, Idaho 83402 failed to geocoded again. Received status' (of course there are four different addresses and four errors.) There is no received status code. I've examined the $Address variable via echo and it seems to be normally formed.

Thanks in advance....

Here's the entire PHP page:

```
<?php

require("../../DatabaseCredentials.php");

define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.googleapis.com");

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Select certain fields in the Houses table
$query = "
SELECT `Active`, `SaleTypeID`, `HouseID`, `Active`, `StreetNumber`, `StreetCardinal`, `StreetName`, `City`, `State`, `ZipCode`, `Latitude`, `Longitude` 
FROM `Houses` 
WHERE `HouseID` = 1519 OR `HouseID` = 1520 OR `HouseID` = 1525 OR `HouseID` = 1526
";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

// Initialize delay in geocode speed
$delay = 0;
$base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/api/geocode/xml?";

// Iterate through the rows, geocoding each address
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $geocode_pending = true;

  while ($geocode_pending) {
    $address = $row["StreetNumber"]." ".$row["StreetCardinal"]." ".$row["StreetName"].", ".$row["City"].", ".$row["State"]." ".$row["ZipCode"];  
    $id = $row["HouseID"];

    $request_url = $base_url . "address=" . urlencode($address) . "&sensor=false";  
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");

    $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;

    if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
      // successful geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;

      $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
      $Latitude = $coordinatesSplit[0];
      $Longitude = $coordinatesSplit[1];
      $query = sprintf("UPDATE brents8_houses " .
             " SET Latitude = '%s', Longitude = '%s' " .
             " WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1;",
             mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
             mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
             mysql_real_escape_string($id));
      $update_result = mysql_query($query);
      if (!$update_result) {
        die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
      }
    } else if (strcmp($status, "620") == 0) {
      // sent geocodes too fast
      $delay += 100000;
    } else {
      // failure to geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      echo "This Address " . $address . " failed to geocoded again. ";
      echo "Received status " . $status . "
\n";
    }
    usleep($delay);
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to use the Pamela Fox & Tom Manshreck article *Geocoding Addresses with PHP MySQL*, written in October 2007, understand that it is written for Geocode v2 and won't work with v3. Here is the code from the article, along with the changes for Geocode v3 that you need to make.

```
<?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

// THE HOST HAS CHANGED, AND A KEY IS NO LONGER REQUIRED.
// v2 define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com");
// v2 define("KEY", "abcdefg");
define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.googleapis.com"); // V3

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}
// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers2 WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}
// Initialize delay in geocode speed
$delay = 0;

// THE BASE URL HAS CHANGED
// v2 $base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?output=xml" . "&key=" . KEY;
$base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/api/geocode/xml?"; // V3

// Iterate through the rows, geocoding each address
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $geocode_pending = true;

  while ($geocode_pending) {
    $address = $row["address"];
    $id = $row["id"];

    // THE REQUEST URL HAS CHANGED
    // v2 $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($address);
    $request_url = $base_url . "address=" . urlencode($address) . "&sensor=false"; // v3

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");

    // THE STATUS CHECK HAS CHANGED
    // v2 $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
    // v2 if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
    $status = $xml->status; // v3
    if (strcmp($status, "OK") == 0) { // v3

      // successful geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
     // $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;          

      // THE COORDINATS SPLIT HAS CHANGED
      // v2 $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
      // v2 $lat = $coordinatesSplit[0];
      // v2 $lng = $coordinatesSplit[1];

      $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat; // v3
      $lng = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng; // v3

      $query = sprintf("UPDATE markers2 " .
             " SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " .
             " WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1;",
             mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
             mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
             mysql_real_escape_string($id));
      $update_result = mysql_query($query);
      if (!$update_result) {
        die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
      }
    } else if (strcmp($status, "620") == 0) {
      // sent geocodes too fast
      $delay += 100000;
    } else {
      // failure to geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      echo "Address " . $address . " failed to geocoded. ";
      echo "Received status " . $status . "
\n";
    }
    usleep($delay);
  }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps all y'all.

Comment: Requires some updates. First of all Lat and Lng are both lowercase so the code fails as is (for me anyway)... also you it is helpful to cast them if you want to use them in any calculations or you get a screen full of warnings:


  $a['lat'] = (float)$xml->result->geometry->location->lat; // v3
  $a['lon'] = (float)$xml->result->geometry->location->lng; // v3

Answer (score 2):

Great job, you need to comment out $coordinates, and location->Lat & Lng should not be capitalized.  It's result->geometry->location->lat & result->geometry->location->lng